# How to use split_part of postgresql inside laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

I want to use [split_part](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-split_part/) inside laravel. My code is like,

```
$results = DB::table('zaiko')
               ->where('soukobango',$souko_bango_for_joining)
               ->join('syouhin1','zaiko.syouhinbango','=','syouhin1.bango')
               ->where('syouhin1.isphoto','is distinct from','1')
               ->select('syouhin1.bango',
                    'syouhin1.kokyakusyouhinbango',
                    'syouhin1.jouhou',
                    'syouhin1.tokuchou',
                    "SPLIT_PART('zaiko.datachar02', '|', 1) as test1")
              ->get();
```

However, it is giving me the following error.

> Undefined table: 7 ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table
>   "SPLIT_PART('zaiko" LINE 1: ...ngo", "syouhin1"."jouhou",
>   "syouhin1"."tokuchou", "SPLIT_PAR... ^ (SQL: select
>   "syouhin1"."bango", "syouhin1"."kokyakusyouhinbango",
>   "syouhin1"."jouhou", "syouhin1"."tokuchou",
>   "SPLIT_PART('zaiko"."datachar02', '|', 1)" as "test1" from "zaiko"
>   inner join "syouhin1" on "zaiko"."syouhinbango" = "syouhin1"."bango"
>   where "soukobango" = 1 and "syouhin1"."isphoto" is distinct from 1)

But if I remove the line with SPLIT_PART then it works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a raw select:

```
->select(DB::raw("syouhin1.bango,
                  syouhin1.kokyakusyouhinbango,
                  syouhin1.jouhou,
                  syouhin1.tokuchou,
                  SPLIT_PART(zaiko.datachar02, '|', 1) AS test1"))
```